# How to randomly select an image using findall and clickall? Sikuli

Tags: python, jython, sikuli

The problem that I'm having is that when using "if image exists, then click image" the script wants to select the top image every time even if there are 8 others. How do I have it randomly select any of the images each time with equal chance?

Example
DOG it will pick this one each time.
DOG I want it to pick this one..
DOG and this one..
DOG  and sometimes this one too.

Answer (score 1):

import random
click(random.choice(list(findAll(("dog-1"))))